# Jquery Ui accordion create icon tag after title

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have accordion with custom font-awesome icons:

```
  $("#accordion").accordion({ 
     icons: {
      header: "icon-chevron-down",
       activeHeader: "icon-chevron-up"
    },
   });
```

How to create it after header text ? `float:right;` not helped because width of header 100% and icons move far from text.

Example of html now:

```
<h2 class="ui-accordion-header ...">
<span class="ui-accordion-header-icon ui-icon icon-chevron-down"></span>
                    My title
</h2>
```

What i need:

```
 <h2 class="ui-accordion-header ...">
                        My title
      <span class="ui-accordion-header-icon ui-icon icon-chevron-down"></span>
    </h2>
```

Comment: why don't you try moving the <span> element out of the <h2> element? it's hard to tell what you're after if we can't see a representation of current and desired states.

Comment: i hope that anyone finds some query ui solution.

Comment: Have you tried to use `position:absolute` on your `<span>` _(...relative to the `<h2>`, that is)_ in order to take it out of the flow so it doesn't matter anymore where the content lies beside it?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use the css **:before**
[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3a%3abefore) or :after